# Неопределенный результат

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu

Доброго времени суток, друзья!
Написал программу, вычисляющую НОД, столкнулся вот с какой проблемой:
при вызове функции один раз - вывод правильный:

```
struct SSimpleFactors factors_1 = simpleFactors(340);
```

Т.е. вызов этой функции выдаст правильный результат: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь же, когда вызываю две функции:

```
    struct SSimpleFactors factors_1 = simpleFactors(340);
    struct SSimpleFactors factors_2 = simpleFactors(160);
```

Результат вовсе неверный, для обоих натуральных чисел: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за чего и сам НОД становиться неверным.
Вот весь код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Predefined constants and structures */

#define FAC_SIZE 50

struct SSimpleFactors
{

    int* array;
    int amount;
};

/* Function prototypes */

struct SSimpleFactors simpleFactors(int number); /* Function returns structure that holds the array of factors and the number of them.

    void outputFactors(struct SSimpleFactors factors); /* Print factors.*/

int countAElements(int* array, int length,
                   int element); /* Count the number of the elements in given array.*/

int lastIn(int* array, int length,
           int element); /* This function returns the last position of element in given array.*/

int* amountOfElements(int* array,
                      int length); /*Returns the array where the even index holds an element and the odd index is the number of elements in the array.*/

int* commonFactors(int* array_1, int length_1, int* array_2,
                   int length_2); /* Function returns array that hold the common factors for array_1 and aarray_2 */

int amax(int value_1,
         int value_2); /*  Returns 1 if value_1 > value_2, otherwise value_2 */

int amin(int value_1,
         int value_2); /*  Returns 1 if value_1 < value_2, otherwise value_2 */

int max(int value_1, int
        value_2); /*  Returns value_1 if value_1 > value_2, otherwise value_2 */

int min(int value_1, int
        value_2); /*  Returns value_1 if value_1 > value_2, otherwise value_2 */

int getLen(int* array,
           int termination_value); /* Function returns length of given array, termination value as a border. */

int findCommonDivider(int* array); /* Return the divider */

int NOD(int* array); /*Whole function */

/* Function defenitions */

int main(void)
{
    struct SSimpleFactors factors_1 = simpleFactors(340);
    struct SSimpleFactors factors_2 = simpleFactors(160);
    outputFactors(factors_1);
    printf("---\n");
    outputFactors(factors_2);
    return 0;
}

int NOD(int* array)
{
    ; /* There is nothing */
}

struct SSimpleFactors simpleFactors(int number)
{
    int amount = 0; /* Number of factors in array.*/
    int position = 0; /* Start position in array */
    static int
    simple_factors[FAC_SIZE]; /* Array where the factors will be stored*/
    int divider = 2; /* Initial value of divider.*/

    while (number != 1)
    {
        if (number % divider == 0)
        {
            number /= divider;
            simple_factors[position] = divider;
            ++position;
            ++amount;
        }
        else
        {
            ++divider;
        }
    }

    struct SSimpleFactors factors;

    factors.array = simple_factors;

    factors.amount = amount;

    return factors;
}

void outputFactors(struct SSimpleFactors factors)
{
    /* This function outputs the content of array's factors .*/
    register int i;

    for (i = 0; i < factors.amount; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", factors.array[i]);
    }
}

int countAElements(int* array, int length, int element)
{
    register int i = 0;
    int amount = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == element)
        {
            ++amount;
        }
    }

    return amount;
}

int countUnduplicatedElements(int* array, int length)
{
    // This fucntion counts the amount of unduplicated elements
    int amount = 0; // Amount of unduplicated elements
    register i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (countAElements(array, length, array[i]) == 1)
        {
            ++amount;
        }
    }

    return amount;
}

int* amountOfElements(int* array, int length)
{
    static int new_amount[FAC_SIZE];
    register int i, j;

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < length;)
    {
        new_amount[j] = array[i];
        ++j;
        new_amount[j] = countAElements(array, length, array[i]);
        i = lastIn(array, length, array[i]) + 1;
        ++j;
    }

    new_amount[j] = 0; /* Add zero as a termination symbol */
    return new_amount;
}

int lastIn(int* array, int length, int element)
{
    // This function returns the last element's position in given array and -1 if there is not element in the array
    register int i;
    int current_position = 0;

    if (countAElements(array, length, element) == 0)
    {
        return -1; // There is not an element in the array
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == element)
            {
                current_position = i;
            }
        }
    }

    return current_position;
}

int* commonFactors(int* array_1, int length_1, int* array_2,
                   int length_2)
{
    static int common_factors[FAC_SIZE];
    register i, j, k;
    int bigger_len;
    int* to_garray;
    int* to_larray;
    int difference = 0;

    if (amax(length_1, length_2) == 1)
    {
        bigger_len = length_1;
        to_garray = array_1;
        to_larray = array_2;
    }
    else
    {
        bigger_len = length_2;
        to_garray = array_2;
        to_larray = array_1;
    }

    for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < bigger_len;)
    {
        if (to_garray[i] == to_larray[j])
        {
            common_factors[k] = to_garray[i];
            ++i;
            ++j;
            ++k;
            difference = max(to_garray[i], to_larray[j]) - min(to_garray[i],
                         to_larray[j]);
            common_factors[k] = max(to_garray[i], to_larray[j]) - difference;
            ++i;
            ++j;
            ++k;
        }
        else
        {
            i += 2;
        }
    }

    ++k;
    common_factors[k] = -1;
    return common_factors;
}

int amax(int value_1, int value_2)
{
    if (value_1 >= value_2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

int amin(int value_1, int value_2)
{
    if (value_1 <= value_2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

int max(value_1, value_2)
{
    if (value_1 >= value_2)
    {
        return value_1;
    }
    else
    {
        return value_2;
    }
}

int min(value_1, value_2)
{
    if (value_1 <= value_2)
    {
        return value_1;
    }
    else
    {
        return value_2;
    }
}

int getLen(int* array, int terminated_value)
{
    register int i;
    int len = 0;

    for (i = 0; array[i] != terminated_value; i++)
    {
        ++len;
    }

    return len;
}

int findCommonDevider(int* array)
{
    int result = 1;
    int temp_result = 0;
    register int i;

    for (i = 0; i < getLen(array, -1) - 1;)
    {
        temp_result = pow(array[i], array[i + 1]);
        result *= temp_result;
        i += 2;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Пожалуйста, помогите, заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для создания массивов нужно использовать `malloc`. Т.е. всюду, где вы возвращаете или как-то передаёте наружу массив, вместо:

```
static int simple_factors[FAC_SIZE]; /* Array where the factors will be stored*/
```

надо делать:

```
int *simple_factors = malloc(FAC_SIZE * sizeof(int));
```

Ну и в конце, когда этот массив вам уже будет не нужен, надо не забыть вызвать `free`.

Comment: Очень помогло Ваше решение.
Искренне благодарен!

Answer (score 2):

Вы, наверное, уже выучили, что нельзя возвращать указатель на локальный объект, и делаете `simple_factors` статическим. Т.е. **единственным** на все время работы программы, и возвращаете указатель на него. И что? После первого вызова он содержит результаты для первого вызова, после второго - для второго. Которые теперь становятся результатами и для первого :(

И еще - излишняя информация - не менее плохо, чем ее недостаток. Не стоит приводить всю программу, а тем паче не стоит давать копии экрана...

P.S. Ничего не буду говорить об *алгоритмической правильности и эффективности* вашего решения, но советую задуматься и об этом...

P.P.S. Не понял, кстати, почему вы считаете, что результат на втором скриншоте для второго числа неверен? `2*2*2*2*2*5 = 160`

P.P.P.S. И еще - в современном C ключевое слово `register` можно смело считать устаревшим и ненужным.

Comment: Благодарю за информацию! 
Если не сложно, не могли бы поделиться информацией насчет того, где можно почитать что-нибудь качественное про алгоритмы?

Comment: Смотрите такого автора, как Кормен. Самое начало - "Алгоритмы. Вводный курс" (для начинающих), самый конец - "Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ" (это уже на профессионалов :)) Если хочется доходчиво - Левитин., "Алгоритмы. Введение в разработку и анализ". Была еще такая Ахо, Хопкрофт, Ульман "Структуры данных и алгоритмы", но она Паскаль-ориентированная :) Классику - Кнут. "Искусство программирования" - надо рассматривать или как справочное пособие (просто чтоб на полке стоял), или как серьезный научный труд по математике (и тогда решать все задачи). Мое личное мнение, у других может быть иное :)

Comment: Еще раз огромное спасибо!